# How to get select value on the server side?

Tags: jquery-ui, google-app-engine

I have jQuery UI combobox element added to my page:

```
<select id="cbCountry" style="display: none; ">
    <option value="1" selected>UK</option>
</select>
```

But when I get its value on the server side (`self.request.get('cbCountry')`), nothing is returned. What can be wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to supply a name instead of (in addition to) an id for an input you want posted.  Only named inputs are transmitted by the browser in a POST.

```
<select id="cbCountry" name="cbCountry" style="display: none; ">
    <option value="1">UK</option>
</select>
```